# Elasticsearch mapping changes during reindexing

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

When performing a reindex in Elasticsearch, the mapping of fields changes.

Previous mapping:

```
"status": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "ignore_above": 10
}
```

New mapping:

```
"status": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
        }
    }
}
```

The command used to perform the reindex, resulting in the mapping change:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "source_index_name"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_index_name"
  }
}
```

Elasticsearch version: 7.13.2

It was expected that the mapping would be preserved. Are there any ways to retain the original mapping when reindexing?

Answer (score 0):

Upon reindexing, only the data is copied to the new index, but neither the mappings nor the settings of the original index.

If you want to preserve the mapping of the original index, you need to create the new target index in advance with the desired mapping, and only then run the reindex operation.

Answer (score 0):

> Reindex requires _source to be enabled for all documents in the
> source.
>
> The destination should be configured as wanted before calling
> _reindex. Reindex does not copy the settings from the source or its associated template.
>
> **Mappings, shard counts, replicas, and so on must be configured ahead
> of time.**
> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

Like Val mentioned one of the method is PUT the mapping in advance like the following:

```
PUT reindex_destination
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "status": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

--- And trigger the reindex.

```
POST _reindex?slices=auto&wait_for_completion=false
{
  "conflicts": "proceed", 
  "source": {
    "index": "reindex_source"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "reindex_destination"
  }
}
```

#### To automate the PUT mapping process, you can use [index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html).

```
PUT /_index_template/reindex_template?pretty
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "reindex_*"
  ],
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
    },
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "status": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 10
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When performing a reindex in Elasticsearch, the mappings are determined by the destination index.

To retain the original mapping, explicitly define the mapping for the destination index before reindexing, ensuring it matches the mapping of the source index.